# Render a functional child component dynamically

Tags: typescript, vuejs2

I have a need to render a component returned from a function (i.e. dynamically created).

My question is, how do I go about doing this?

I have tried doing something like this in the parent component:

```
<template>
  ...
  <component :is="aboutUsParagraphs()" />
</template>
```

The function call will return a functional component created like this:

```
Vue.component("app-about-us", {
  functional: true,
  render(createElement: CreateElement) {
    return createElement("div",
               createElement("p", ["Something about us"]));
  }
});
```

This compiles fine, and I get no errors in the console, but when I look in the DOM, I only see an empty `div` element.

What am I missing?

Thanks!

P.S. I also want to be able to render an array of these kinds of components using the `v-for` directive, so a solution that allows for that would be most preferred. Thanks again.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<div id="dynamic-component-demo" class="demo">
  <template>
    <component :is="aboutUsParagraphs()" />
  </template>
</div>

<script src="vue.js"></script>
<script>

  new Vue({
    el: '#dynamic-component-demo',
    data: {
    },
    methods: {
        aboutUsParagraphs(){
          return Vue.component("app-about-us", {
              functional: true,
              render(createElement) {
                return createElement("div",
                  [createElement("p", ["Something about us"])]);
              }
          });
        }
    }
  })
</script>
```

This works for me.
You can refer to https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/render-function.html#createElement-Arguments for the arguments of createElement function.

Also, the value of `:is` should be either a string or a option object as stated here:
https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/components.html#Dynamic-Components
So instead of the above code, following should be better.

```
  new Vue({
    el: '#dynamic-component-demo',
    data: {
    },
    methods: {
        aboutUsParagraphs(){
          return {
            functional: true,
            render(createElement) {
              return createElement("div",
                [createElement("p", ["Something about us"])]);
            }
          }
        }
    }
```

Comment: So from what you have posted, it seems that my mistake was not wrapping the `component` part in `template` tags, because the `template` part you see in that question was for the parent not the child, as you can tell from the tilde in there. I will try your suggestion, thanks

Comment: no problem:) i guess it’s more about the createElement arguments. When i put the string into an array it works fine.

Comment: That was it! The array thing was the issue. I wasn't paying attention. Thanks for your help